How to Exclude Internal Users from Odoo 17 Contact List
Currently, Odoo displays internal users in the contact list, which I wish to hide. I have a filter in place that allows operators to see only assigned users with the following criteria:
['|',('operator_user_ids', 'in', [user.id]), ('id','=',user.id)]

This filter functions correctly but includes internal users in the list. I need to modify it to exclude internal users from the list altogether.
